# Integrating react-hot-loader in Create-React-App without Ejecting

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am working on a project using create-react-app and redux. The problem is that i can't seem to find a way how to integrate react hot loader without ejecting the app which is something i'm not allowed to do in my project. Is there any way to integrate RHL?

Comment: Sounds like you are in uncharted territory here

Comment: will it be helpful?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIMjnWuA9B0